# How can I type in a class in scala and send it to a remote end?

Tags: java, class, scala, serialization, read-eval-print-loop

I have an interface called CodeInterface on a remote server (running Java). What I wanna do now is to manually type-in a class implementing CodeInterface in scala REPL, send it to the remote server, and let the server invoke some method in it. How can I do that?

I've already been able to send a scala script to the remote server and invoke it. However, I cannot get a typed-in class serialized and sent.

Comment: It is hardly implementable, IMHO. Serialization works for objects rather than for classes. So it is usually required to have precompiled class on the other side to deserialize object. Whenever you have some function it compiles to a method of an anonymous class. If you really-really wanted to send the class, then you would bother compiling it by yourself and stream the .class over the connection.

Comment: Do you know how can I compile a class that is typed into a scala REPL? I'm doing a demo and need to show my coding in a single terminal window that runs scala REPL.

Comment: I don't. Seems a bit simpler to send plain text and feed it to REPL on the server side.